# How to iterate over an array of strings with spaces bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, for-loop

What i'm trying to do, is to list all my aliases kinda like this, when i call `functions` in my bash terminal

```
$ functions
    functions -> List all functions
    fs -> Determine size of a file or total size of a directory
```

That ends up happening, is it list every word, so the output looks like this

```
functions
->
List
all
...
```

How do iterate get an array like

`['functions -> List all functions', 'fs -> Determine size of a file or total size of a directory]`

that I can iterate over?

My implementation is listed below

```
declare -a dotfilesFunctionAlias=()

function appendFunction(){
    dotfilesFunctionAlias+=( "$1->$2" )
}

appendFunction "functions" "List all functions";
function functions(){
    for func in ${dotfilesFunctionAlias[@]}; do
        echo $func;
    done;
}
```

Comment: not sure what any of this has to do with `aliases` ... ??? **assuming** your array is already populated and your only issue at this point is iterating over the array, consider iterating over the array indices, eg: `for idx in ${!dotfilesFunctionAlias[@]}; do echo "${dotfilesFunctionAlias[${idx}]}"; done`

Comment: I guess the "aliases" is bad naming :/

That did the job! Thanks ❤️

Comment: BTW, in general, `function foo() {` is bad form. Use the POSIX-standard form `foo() {` with no `function`, or the legacy ksh form `function foo {` with no `()`; otherwise, you're incompatible with **both** POSIX and legacy ksh. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete -- there are relevant entries in both 1st and 3rd tables.

Comment: ...and to reinforce what @xhinne's answer says about `printf` being preferable to `echo`, see the excellent answer by Stephane on [Why is `printf` better than `echo`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113) over at [unix.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should quote your variables (using an unquoted variable should be the exception):

```
for func in "${dotfilesFunctionAlias[@]}"; do
    echo "$func";
done;
```

Without double quotes, `${dotfilesFunctionAlias[@]}` is expanded and `func` takes the value of each word in turn. Double quotes preserve the spaces.

Also, you should be cautious with `echo` and use `printf` instead. If the name of one of your functions starts with a valid `echo` option (`-e`, `-n`, etc), then `echo "$func"` will not work as intended.

Finally, with `printf` you don't need any loop at all. The following command is enough to print your array.

```
printf '%s\n' "${dotfilesFunctionAlias[@]}"
```